# Get system date with BadBoy software for testing

Tags: javascript, testing, sysdate, badboy

I am creating a script for application tests, in order to export it and use it with JMeter.

I would need to get the system date as a variable, at the script level, not the environment, but I can not do it in any way.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, create at the start of the badboy script a js script(At the beginning of the step, Add / JScript).

[JScript in badboy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNtPZ.png)

with the following content:

[Script get date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeE21.png)

To be used from the badboy script $ {sysdate}.